# Predictions in the R package "mstate"

Tags: r

I have fitted a multistate model in the R package “mstate” and would like to predict transition probabilities (and standard errors) for cohort of patients with some values of covariates taken from the data and others set to certain values?

Let’s say my model had the covariates sex, facility, and treatment, and I have a dataset of 10 patients (see below). How could I predict the transition probabilities for my cohort of patients (the values for sex and fac should be taken from the data) and only vary the values of treatment (i.e. compare the transition probabilities that we would see if everyone would be treated (treatment == 1 for all patients) vs. nobody would be treated (treatment ==0 for all patients)? The caption of the resulting plot would be: Comparison of the predicted transition probabilities for all patients enrolled in my study assuming that A) everyone would be treated and B) nobody would be treated. I do not want to predict transition probabilities for example patients (i.e. all covariates set to specific values) as described in Wreede et al. 2011, Figure 5, p.20) but make predictions for the whole cohort with levels of sex and fac taken from the date and only vary the levels of treatment.

```
ID  sex  fac  treatment  
1  f  HC  0  
2  f  DC  1  
3  m  HC  1  
4  m  HC  0  
5  f  HC  1  
6  f  DC  0  
7  f  HC  0  
8  m  DC  1  
9  f  HC 0  
10  m  DC  0
```

I have read the tutorials written by the authors of the package (Wreede et al. 2011; Putter et al. 2007) and googled extensively but could not find a solution to this problem. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,
Andreas

References:

Comment: Wouldn't you need to have multiple (ordered) observations on the IDs?